# Duda como obtener location de un usuario

Tags: html5, geolocalización

se que la comunidad stackoverflow son estrictos con las preguntas pero me ha surgido una nececidad y nunca habia trabajado con **geolocation** , la cosa es que quisiera saber si hay una manera de obtener la ubicacion de un usuario mediante un evento  es decir tengo el siguiente codigo de ejemplo de lo que nececito hacer..

```
<select id="countries">
<option value="United Stated">United Stated</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>
```

**js file**

```
$("#countries").on("change",function(){

    /*en el evento on change del select me gustaria determinar 
      si el pais que el usuario elegio es verdaderamente su pais
      es decir que determine su location mediante on change
      y si no es su pais en verdad me mande una alerta con alguna 
       advertencia 
    */

})
```

alguna recomendacion de como podria hacer lo que quiero? si  existe alguna libreria o framework que que me ayude con lo que necicito hacer seria genial. si no  alguien me podria iluminar una idea que metodos exiten para hacer lo que quiero ya sea en **javascript** o **php** cualquier tip os agradeceria un monton gracias!

Comment: Solo tienes que buscar en Google. Para PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php Para Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation

Answer (score 1):

No es tan trivial. El api de GeoLocation de HTML5 te permite hacer un llamado del tipo:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  console.log('la posición es', position);
}, function(err) {
  console.warn(err);
});
```

Que, en el mejor de los casos (el navegador soporta geolocation, el navegador te autoriza a pedir la geolocalización -google sólo lo permite a dominios servidos con https- y el usuario acepta compartir su posición) te devolverá como respuesta una instancia de [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Position) que a su vez tiene coordenadas.

Para asociar esas coordenadas a un país tendrías que buscar un servicio que ofrezca ese tipo de API. Google Maps tiene [un endpoint para hacer Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) que acepta un par de coordenadas y devuelve un objeto que contiene país y subdivisiones administrativas (opcionalmente el zipcode y la dirección). Necesitas un API Key para probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

encontre una forma de hacerlo con una api super buena que obtiene el tipo de direcciones ip de todos los paises ,

como dicen por ahy es importante investigar les comparto lo que hice quisas les pueda servir en algun proyecto

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/', function(data) {
  JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

 var country =data.country_name;

   

$("#countries").change(function(){
var c=$(this).val();


    if(c!=country ){
    
      alert(c+" is no your country")
       $("#response").html("your country is: "+country )
    
    }else{
    
      alert(c+" is your country Thank you")
       $("#response").html("your country is: "+country )
    
    }
  

    
    })
    
});

})
```

```html
<select id="countries">
<option value="United Stated">United Stated</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
</select>


<div id="response"></div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```